# SQL query to find duplicate in one table and if not found move them to another table

Tags: sql, salesforce

I have two tables

**table 1:**

```
cust id    name    dob        join date
1         roger    1/12/2012  8/12/2012
2         ranjeet  8/11/1988  9/12/2012
3         pinki    14/12/1990 10/12/2012
4          david   5/12/1947 1/1/2017
6          Tim     5/12/2012 1/1/2017
```

**table 2:**

```
cust id    name    dob       Join date
1          roger   1/12/2012 8/12/2012
4          david   5/12/1947 1/1/2017
1          roger   1/12/2012 8/12/2012
6          Tim     5/12/2012 1/1/2017
3          pinki   14/12/1990 10/12/2012
2          ranjeet 8/11/1988 9/12/2012
```

**The result table I want to get:**

```
cust id    name    dob        join date
4          david   5/12/1947   1/1/2017
6          tim     5/12/2012   5/1/2017
```

`cust_id` is the primary key in table1 but not in table 2 but it is unique and primary key in table1. so here is the situation data is coming through APIs in table 1 with unique entry but at the same time it is also pushed into table 2 where it might get duplicated.

I just want to get ONLY those unique subscribers from table 2 after checking their `cust_id` in table 1 who have join date before today -3 days.

assume `cust_id` 4 and 6 were also present in table 1 but their join date is before today -3 days so they are somewhat old for the table.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: What did you try so far? Your logic seems simple enough for a normal `LEFT JOIN`  query to get the result. But your expected output is from table 1, not `ONLY those unique subscribers from table 2` as you describe

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if undserstood correctly but I would go with:

```
select * from table2
where  cust_id not in (select cust_id from table1 where join_date <= sysdate - 3)
```

I assumed Oracle DB, therefore 'sysdate'.

PS. Table 2 has duplicate row with cust_id = 1. If Cust_id is primary key then this should not happen

Comment: sorry my bad.. in table 2 there is another field which is mentioned as primary key but the only column to match with table1 is cust_id and I have to take care of duplicates entry in result table.. Thank you so much for your above answer